Set position in geometry nodes makes object disappear
I have a simple object whose position I would like to link to another object.
I append a Geometry Node to that simple object, use the Set Position field and plug a vector to the Input position (later on the vector will come from the other object's position). And the object disappears. How come ?



You set the position of each vertex to (0, 0, 0) so rhe whole mesh is shrunk down to the origin point.

If your objective is to translate (not to deform) the object the GN modifier is attached to, I would recommend a Transform Geometry node over a Set Position node because it is optimized when the same displacement is applied to all the vertices.

...or, if you want to use the Set Position node, do not plug a vector in the Position input, but the Offset. This will move all vertices by the amount of the vector relative to their original position.
